# Magento 2 install folder

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I am new to Magento 2 and was using **composer** to install it. Have already cloned the repo from Magento GitHub account.

One thing I couldn't find information about was when installing Magento 2 on localhost do I need to place it under this docroot `/var/www/magento2` or can it live outside this folder structure? Fro example just under `magento2`?

Comment: It should depends on your web server setting. Like apache, it will work if you setup a vhost on /var/www/html/testing_magento and use composer install to the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it anywhere on your system just update the Apache HTTP server configuration accordingly. The default docroot is `/var/www/html` or `/srv/www/htdocs` depending upon your os distribution. And update the apache config file. For example for ubuntu

```
@@ -219,3 +219,7 @@
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
+ServerName localhost
+<Directory "/var/www/html">
+AllowOverride  All
+</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache2, don't change any setting and try to move the folder `magento2` in `/var/www/html/public_html/`.

Then, in your browser, go to `localhost/public_html/magento2`

Answer (score 0):

Depends wich folder you use to guide your domain. If you use mamp,wamp the easiest way is to directly put it in de www folder and unzip. Check you php versions and myql.

Answer (score 0):

Typical setups are /var/www/html. This is dependent upon your vhost files, PHP and MySql setups.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are using the Apache Server the document root was default set to `/var/www/html`
2. When you are using the Xampp server the document root default is `/opt/lampp/htdocs`

After coming in the current directory run the composer command to install the magento :

```
 composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:<version> <install-directory-name>
```

After successful installation you can browse the url to open magento :

```
localhost/<install-directory-name>/
```

install-directory-name its may be magento2 or any other else.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it really depends on your server configuration (Apache, Nginx).